# Ionic Cordova Build Error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to build ionic app but this returns error. I tried whole day to figure it out but no success. I tried installing different version f Java, changing PATH etc as mentioned in other question but no luck.
This is the error I get when I try to build project.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/pc/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
(node:7743) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
at Object.exports.spawn (/home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
at GradleBuilder.build (/home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:223:23)
at /home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:151:24
at _fulfilled (/home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
at /home/pc/University/SmartBoardWork/smsApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
(node:7743) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.    This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7743) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[17:56:02]  lint finished in 3.56 s

Ionic Version

```
3.20.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With you'r JAVA_HOME path i deduce you used linux so can u try this please

```
sudo chmod 755 "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin/gradle"
```

Of course you need to replace my path by you'r gradle path ;)

the initial chmod is 644 if you wan't to get back after the build

Comment: Yes, I am using Linux Mint. I changed the permission of gradle but same error still.

Comment: I solved it by removing cordova-plugin-fcm from project.And then adding it again.